# Django mark / select some data in listview

Tags: python, django, web-frameworks

i have listview class like this :

```
class VechileListView(ListView):
  model = Vechile
  template_name = 'store/arm_list.html'
  context_object_name = 'arm'
```

in model `Vechile`, there are field `tanggal_stnk`

it work fine, now the problem i want to marked red some data in `tanggal_stnk`
here are the template :

```
  {% if arm %}
     {% for data in arm %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.tanggal_stnk }}</td>
   .......
```

`tanggal_stnk` is a `datefield`, for example i want to mark text to red color, if the date is today..

what i already try to add something like this in Class `VechileListView`

```
    class VechileListView(ListView):
      model = Vechile
      template_name = 'store/arm_list.html'
      context_object_name = 'arm'

      def expiry(request):
        expired_stnk = Vechile.objects.filter(tanggal_stnk = datetime.now())
        context = {
            'expired_stnk' : expired_stnk
        }
        return render(request, 'store/arm_list.html', context)
```

is it possible in listView, and how to implement it on the template, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the queryset with a boolean that specifies if it expires today:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.utils.timezone import now

class VechileListView(ListView):
      model = Vechile
      template_name = 'store/arm_list.html'
      context_object_name = 'arm'

      def get_queryset(request):
          return Vechile.objects.annotate(
              expires_today=ExpressionWrapper(
                  Q(tanggal_stnk=now().date()),
                  output_field=BooleanField()
              )
          )
```

then we render it with:

```
{% for data in arm %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td{% if data.expires_today %} style="color:#0000ff"{% endif %}>{{ data.tanggal_stnk }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: so we need to make new field expires_today ?

Comment: @shofyankhan: no, an annotation simply means that for *this* queryset, there will be an extra attribute.

Comment: @shofyankhan: please take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: it makes error "Cannot resolve keyword 'expires_today' into field", its like we need to create another field

Comment: @shofyankhan: sorry forgot to rewrite `.filter` to `.annotate` in the `get_queryset`.